# Joining decimal columns in DAX when using GENERATEDSERIES

Tags: powerbi, relationship, dax

I have two tables in Power BI, one generated table and one from raw data with a calculated column, each of them have a decimal column *formatted* to have 1 decimal place.

*generated table DAX:*

`Tenths = GENERATESERIES(0, 2000, 0.1)`

*Calculated column DAX:*

`RoundedTime = MROUND('LIVE Network'[Time], 0.1)`

*Formatting:*

[image: Formatting of both columns]

When attempting to join those two columns in a relationship, the resulting visual only has very sparse data, indicating that the join isn't working as I expected.

I believe this is due to "slightly off" errors, where the actual values contained in the columns are not *exectly* rounded to 1 decimal place, indeed if I remove the formatting from the generated table I can see that most of the values are in fact similar to `5.9999999999` rather than `6.0`.  As shown below:

[image: general formatted column]

[image: actual output from generate series]

At some point the numbers correctly show a 1 decimal place value, and at these points my visual shows data, so I strongly believe that the rounding issues here are what are causing the join the fail.

The calculate column from the other table *does* have an exact rounding to 1 decimal place when changing the format to general.

Are there any workarounds or actual solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a calculated column to the generated table solved my issue.  Noting that the `MROUND` functioned correctly, I tried that on the generated table, and it solved my problem.

So, with a generated table created with:

`Tenths = GENERATESERIES(0, 2000, 0.1)`

I added a calculated column to that table with:

`RoundedTenths = MROUND(Tenths[Tenth], 0.1)`

Put simply, using `MROUND` correctly rounds decimals.